# how to take the id in the filter table as input and get the data as output

Tags: php, html, mysql, fpdf

I have been working on this website which prints the Forms of the users who have submitted them. I used a button 'view form' to generate PDF of the form through FPDF. 
 my problem is I cant print the form which I have clicked. Instead the last form which has submitted has generated.
 here is the code:
Homepage.php:

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','logindb1');

$output='';
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
// storing session
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE username LIKE 
'%$username%'") or die("Could not search!");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);


if($count == 0){
     echo "There was no search result!";
}
else{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){


 echo '<table width = "30%" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing ="2" border = "2px">
                <tr>
        <td><strong> ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong> username</strong> </td>

        <td><strong> EC. no</strong> </td>

        <td><strong> Division</strong> </td>
        <td><strong> ProjectCode</strong> </td>

        <td><strong> date of journey</strong> </td>
        <td><strong> return date</strong> </td>
        <td><strong> From </strong> </td>
        <td><strong> To</strong> </td>
        <td><button  type="submit" name="but" >view form</button></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
        <td> <input  type="text" name="dbid" value='.$row['ID'].' size="4" readonly ></td>
        <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>

        <td>'.$row['ecno'].'</td>

        <td>'.$row['division'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['code'].'</td>


    if (isset($_POST['but'])){




  $dbid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['dbid']);

  $_SESSION['dbid']= $dbid;


  header('location: invoice.php');


 }
 ?>
```

Invoice.php:

```
<?php
session_start();



$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "logindb1");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "something went wrong with the connection" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $dbid = $_SESSION['dbid'];
  $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users2  WHERE ID ='$dbid'");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        $ID    =$row['ID'];
        $username=$row['username'];
        $email=$row['email'];
        $ecno =$row['ecno'];
        $gradepay=$row['gradepay'];
```

In Homepage.php i have output ID as input text box and same i have taken as input id.Is this method correct? is there something more efficient. please Help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you does not have session_start(); in your first file.

```
<?php
session_start();

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','logindb1');
```

When you want to set or put on sessions you should do this.

Also there are an issue that you did not closed your string:

```
echo '<table width = "30%" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing ="2" border = "2px">
            <tr>
    <td><strong> ID</strong></td>
    <td><strong> username</strong> </td>

    <td><strong> EC. no</strong> </td>

    <td><strong> Division</strong> </td>
    <td><strong> ProjectCode</strong> </td>

    <td><strong> date of journey</strong> </td>
    <td><strong> return date</strong> </td>
    <td><strong> From </strong> </td>
    <td><strong> To</strong> </td>
    <td><button  type="submit" name="but" >view form</button></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
    <td> <input  type="text" name="dbid" value='.$row['ID'].' size="4" readonly ></td>
    <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>

    <td>'.$row['ecno'].'</td>

    <td>'.$row['division'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['code'].'</td> </tr></table>';
```

Comment: hey. I did that but still i cant get the form detail which i have clicked instead the last submitted form.

Comment: are you sure that $_SESSION['dbid'] and $row has value? you can check with echo  $_SESSION['dbid']; and print_r($row);